# How to refer to `../data/` directory in controllers without hard coding a path?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Assuming your Zend Framework 2 application needs to store data in `data/documents/`, how would you refer to directory `data/` in controllers without hard coding a path and maybe without using a relative path?

I'm currently thinking about defining a DATA_DIR constant in `public/index.php` but I'm not sure, if it's the best solution to relay on a hard coded constant name in all controllers...

Is there a way to set this up via `global.conf.php` or `application.config` or any other common solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is an elegant solution already exists for this problem.

See zf2 [skeleton application's index.php on line 6](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/index.php#L6):

```
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

After adding this line to your app's index.php, you can use `unlink('data/foo.txt')`, `mkdir('data/bar')` like filesystem methods without worrying about paths.